# Passing HTML checkmark through JSON into a table with Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, knockout.js

I have a large table filled with a bunch of data using knockout.JS. Some of this data needs to be replaced with HTML checkboxes and selects but it is not on a consistent basis. I have an array of objects that contains all my data. To simplify, each object has 3 properties. Title, value, and format. I am trying to only change the value cells of the table where the format is a checkbox or select.

For example, the original table looks like this:

```
Title   | Value | Format
--------+-------+------- 
Height  | 5     | int
Length  | 7     | int
true    | 1     | checkbox
require | 0     | checkbox
```

But I want it like this:

```
Title   | Value | Format
--------+-------+------- 
Height  | 5     | int
Length  | 7     | int
true    | ☑     | checkbox
require | ☐     | checkbox
```

Example code (PHP):

First I loop through the array of objects and if the format property is "checkbox" then insert the HTML Checkbox instead of the value.

```
        .....loop....

        if($format == "Checkbox"){
            $value = '<input type="checkbox"></input>';
        }
```

I then use `json_encode(array);`

(JS) here is the ajax success

```
success: function(data){
    var valve = JSON.parse(data);
};
```

I then looped through each object in the valve array and pulled the wanted properties:

```
for(var i=0, l=valve.length; i<l; i++){         
    if(valve[i]['formatfor(var i=0, l=valve.length; i<l; i++){          
        if(valve[i]['format']=="checkbox"){
            var formatHTML = '<input type="checkbox"></input>';
        };

        var dataRow ={
            title: valve[i]['title'],
            value: valve[i]['value'],
            format: formatHTML
        };

        //push each row to valveData which is a ko.observableArray()    
        self.valveData.push(dataRow);

};
```

My table populates fine but I end up with the raw HTML:`<input type="checkbox"></input>` not the actual element. Is this a problem with knockout or with my JSON? MY JSON returns the HTML in quotes since it is stored as a string, is there a way to remove them or something?

Higher level question, should I be doing it this way? or should I process the format type within my data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using Knockout at all.

For using Knockout:

- Return a pure JSON object with properties (¡¡not a generate HTML!!)
- Optional: ideally, get the JSON using ajax, instead of writing the object definition directly in your page body. I.e, your php code should return a JSON object, and you should use soemthing like `jQuery.getJSON` to get that data direectly from the PHP server
- Insert your JSON object into a knockout `viewModel`, i.e. map the properties from your JSON.You can use `ko.mapping` plugin to do this automatically. This will convert your JSOn object arrays into `observableArray`, and your JSON object properties into `observable`
- Create a template to render the object
- Bind the object to the template

As to showing a checkbox or simply the text you can use knockout `if` binding.

Your template should look somehting like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody data-bind='foreach: row'>
      <tr>
         <td data-bind='text: title'>
         </td>
         <td>
            <!-- ko if: format=='Checkbox' -->
               <input type='check' data-bind='checked: value`/>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: format!='Checkbox' -->
               <!-- ko text: value --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
         </td>
         <td data-bind='text: format'>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Your JSON object should be something like this:

```
[
   { "title": "height", "value": "5", "format": "int"},
   { "title": "length", "value": "7", "format": "int"},
   { "title": "true", "value": "1", "format": "checkbox"},
   { "title": "required", "value": "0", "format": "checkbox"},
]
```

Your javascript should be soemthing like this:

```
$.getJSON('... your PHP url ...').done(function(data) {
    var viewModel = // construct from data, by hand, or with ko.mapping
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

NOTE: if you don't use AJAX, you can directly define the var or the model on the page content, and make only the call to `applyBindings`. *NOTE: I'm not expert at PHP but I knwo there is a way to serialize a PHP object directly to JSON, so that making the AJAX part is extremely easy. [Please, see this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).*

Comment: I must not have made it clear that I cut out most of my code to save space. I am doing all of your suggestions (JSON,AJAX,Viewmodel,binding to observable array, etc.) Your suggestion of the containerless control syntax was what I needed so thanks for that. I edited your code since you messed up the closing comment tags which caused the whole thing to break. ( > instead of -->)

Comment: apologies, I tried to edit your post to fix your mistakes but I guess that is not the proper way to do things and so it was rejected. I added my own answer with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the containerless control above was incorrect but the idea was good. Here is the fixed code

```
<table>
   <tbody data-bind='foreach: row'>
      <tr>
         <td data-bind='text: title'>
         </td>
         <td>
            <!-- ko if: format=='Checkbox' -->
               <input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: value`/>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: format!='Checkbox' -->
               <!-- ko text: value --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
         </td>
         <td data-bind='text: format'>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```